# Upgrading to Azure (Microsoft) websocket not acknowledged

Tags: azure, websocket, server, client, azure-web-app-service

Due to constraints of current project, I am having to write the WebSocket protocol by hand in C++. I am able to get the authorization key, but when I try to upgrade the next socket connection, the server stalls after getting a completed MIME header. Then when I send anything after it, I get a 400 error. I do not get an acknowledgement from the server that the connection has been upgraded to a WebSocket. Here is a dump:

```
=========================================================================
POST /sts/v1.0/issueToken HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 21cedc8aaab847369294240b2122b08d
Origin: https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.cognitive.microsoft.com&data=04%7C01%7Cv-lufil%40microsoft.com%7C427ffe760b7a4f6ffe6a08d4d8fa0613%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636372015735060988%7CUnknown%7CVW5rbm93bnx7IlYiOiIwLjAuMDAwMCIsIlAiOiJXaW4zMiIsIkFOIjoiT3RoZXIifQ%3D%3D%7C-1&sdata=823HpmiJeZ54tzq6CpX86ZS8B0yUiOYSNMXvrmDSunA%3D&reserved=0
User-Agent: Gideon/0.0.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 495
Content-Type: application/jwt; charset=us-ascii
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
apim-request-id: 00fe24bc-ba53-4d91-9363-ea7fddfe2a5a
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Operation-Location
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 15:21:40 GMT

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3BlZWNoLnBsYXRmb3JtLmJpbmcuY29tIiwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLWlkIjoiZmMwOGVlNGM5ZmNkNGI0MWFmNTZiNzJmZDliZTE4ZWEiLCJwcm9kdWN0LWlkIjoiQmluZy5TcGVlY2guUHJldmlldyIsImNvZ25pdGl2ZS1zZXJ2aWNlcy1lbmRwb2ludCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLmNvZ25pdGl2ZS5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2ludGVybmFsL3YxLjAvIiwiYXp1cmUtcmVzb3VyY2UtaWQiOiIiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bXMuY29nbml0aXZlc2VydmljZXMiLCJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bXMuc3BlZWNoIiwiZXhwIjoxNTAxNjAxNDk5fQ.2RQhid_B45fN5M2BmUlodhIe4Xxx71Ws1b03JylERUw
=========================================================================
POST /speech/recognition/dictation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3BlZWNoLnBsYXRmb3JtLmJpbmcuY29tIiwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLWlkIjoiZmMwOGVlNGM5ZmNkNGI0MWFmNTZiNzJmZDliZTE4ZWEiLCJwcm9kdWN0LWlkIjoiQmluZy5TcGVlY2guUHJldmlldyIsImNvZ25pdGl2ZS1zZXJ2aWNlcy1lbmRwb2ludCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLmNvZ25pdGl2ZS5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2ludGVybmFsL3YxLjAvIiwiYXp1cmUtcmVzb3VyY2UtaWQiOiIiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bXMuY29nbml0aXZlc2VydmljZXMiLCJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bXMuc3BlZWNoIiwiZXhwIjoxNTAxNjAxNDk5fQ.2RQhid_B45fN5M2BmUlodhIe4Xxx71Ws1b03JylERUw
Connection: upgrade
Content-Length: 8002
Content-Type: audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000
Host: speech.platform.bing.com
Path: audio
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Z2lkZW9ucm9ja3MK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Gideon/0.0.1
X-RequestId: 21cedc8aaab847369294240b2122b08d
X-Timestamp: 2017-08-01T15:21:40



HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Exception: 4xx Client failure
```

Note that the server does not reply despite getting two "\r\n" to indicate an end of MIME header. When I send anything afterwards I get a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

According to your dump logs, it seems that you want to use Microsoft's Speech Service to convert the speech to text.

By using Microsoft's Speech Service,the 400 error means you don't have applied all the required parameters and HTTP headers and that the values are correct.

I found your request missed the X-ConnectionId in your request.

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol#connection-identifier):

> The Microsoft Speech Service requires that all clients include a unique id to identify the connection. Clients must include the X-ConnectionId header when starting a web socket handshake. The X-ConnectionId header value must be a universally unique identifier. Web socket upgrade requests that do not include the X-ConnectionId, that do not specify a value for the X-ConnectionId header, or that do not include a valid universally unique identifier value will be rejected by the service with a 400 Bad Request response.

So I suggest you could add the identify id and test again.